# Post link in angular equivalent in knockout

Tags: angularjs, knockout.js

In angular we have post link function in which we can process actions that are required after child elements linking.

Similarly i need to know any functions in knockout except afterRender.

My Scenario is to bind the datasource to table which is rendered by jsrender template with ko template inside

```
<script type="text/jsrender">
<tr>
... // once more ko template here inside
<tr>
</script>
```

i am unable to bind the row data (From js render) to descendants in table

any suggestions